# MoonMail-UI cannot build properly using reactjs / web-pack

Tags: reactjs, webpack, moonmail

> node -v: v.4.4.5
>
> npm -v: 4.3.0
>
> os: windows 10

Steps to reproduce the problem:

1. git clone git@github.com:microapps/MoonMail-UI.git
2. cd moonmail-ui
3. npm install
4. npm build
5. ... error occurs ...

> ERROR in ./src/styles/core.scss
>   Module build failed: ReferenceError: self is not defined
>
> ```
> at C:\dev\test-project\node_modules\style-loader\index.js!C:\dev\test-project\node_modules\css-loader\index.js?sourceMap&-minimize&modules&importLoaders=
> ```
>
> 1&localIdentName=[name]**[local]**[hash:base64:5]!C:\dev\test-project\node_modules\postcss-loader\index.js!C:\dev\test-project\node_modules\sass-loader\index
>   .js?sourceMap!C:\dev\test-project\src\styles\core.scss:99:30
>
> ```
> at C:\dev\test-project\node_modules\style-loader\index.js!C:\dev\test-project\node_modules\css-loader\index.js?sourceMap&-minimize&modules&importLoaders=
> ```
>
> 1&localIdentName=[name]**[local]**[hash:base64:5]!C:\dev\test-project\node_modules\postcss-loader\index.js!C:\dev\test-project\node_modules\sass-loader\index
>   .js?sourceMap!C:\dev\test-project\src\styles\core.scss:94:47
>
> ```
> at module.exports (C:\dev\test-project\node_modules\style-loader\index.js!C:\dev\test-project\node_modules\css-loader\index.js?sourceMap&-minimize&module
> ```
>
> s&importLoaders=1&localIdentName=[name]**[local]**[hash:base64:5]!C:\dev\test-project\node_modules\postcss-loader\index.js!C:\dev\test-project\node_modules\s
>   ass-loader\index.js?sourceMap!C:\dev\test-project\src\styles\core.scss:116:68)
>
> ```
> at Object.<anonymous> (C:\dev\test-project\node_modules\style-loader\index.js!C:\dev\test-project\node_modules\css-loader\index.js?sourceMap&-minimize&mo
> ```
>
> dules&importLoaders=1&localIdentName=[name]**[local]**[hash:base64:5]!C:\dev\test-project\node_modules\postcss-loader\index.js!C:\dev\test-project\node_modul
>   es\sass-loader\index.js?sourceMap!C:\dev\test-project\src\styles\core.scss:400:36)
>
> ```
> at __webpack_require__ (C:\dev\test-project\node_modules\style-loader\index.js!C:\dev\test-project\node_modules\css-loader\index.js?sourceMap&-minimize&m
> ```
>
> odules&importLoaders=1&localIdentName=[name]**[local]**[hash:base64:5]!C:\dev\test-project\node_modules\postcss-loader\index.js!C:\dev\test-project\node_modu
>   les\sass-loader\index.js?sourceMap!C:\dev\test-project\src\styles\core.scss:21:30)
>
> ```
> at C:\dev\test-project\node_modules\style-loader\index.js!C:\dev\test-project\node_modules\css-loader\index.js?sourceMap&-minimize&modules&importLoaders=
> ```
>
> 1&localIdentName=[name]**[local]**[hash:base64:5]!C:\dev\test-project\node_modules\postcss-loader\index.js!C:\dev\test-project\node_modules\sass-loader\index
>   .js?sourceMap!C:\dev\test-project\src\styles\core.scss:65:18
>
> ```
> at Object.<anonymous> (C:\dev\test-project\node_modules\style-loader\index.js!C:\dev\test-project\node_modules\css-loader\index.js?sourceMap&-minimize&mo
> ```
>
> dules&importLoaders=1&localIdentName=[name]**[local]**[hash:base64:5]!C:\dev\test-project\node_modules\postcss-loader\index.js!C:\dev\test-project\node_modul
>   es\sass-loader\index.js?sourceMap!C:\dev\test-project\src\styles\core.scss:68:10)
>
> ```
> at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)                                                                                                                                                          
> at Object.loaderContext.exec (C:\dev\test-project\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:94:6)   
>
> at Object.<anonymous> (C:\dev\test-project\node_modules\extract-text-webpack-plugin\loader.js:112:21)
>
> at Compiler.<anonymous> (C:\dev\test-project\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:251:10)     
>
> at C:\dev\test-project\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:442:12                                                                                                          
> at next (C:\dev\test-project\node_modules\tapable\lib\Tapable.js:138:11)      
>
> at Compiler.<anonymous> (C:\dev\test-project\node_modules\extract-text-webpack-plugin\loader.js:93:4)
>
> at next (C:\dev\test-project\node_modules\tapable\lib\Tapable.js:140:14)      
>
> at Compiler.<anonymous> (C:\dev\test-project\node_modules\webpack\lib\CachePlugin.js:61:4)    
>
> at Compiler.applyPluginsAsyncSeries (C:\dev\test-project\node_modules\tapable\lib\Tapable.js:142:13)      
>
> at Compiler.<anonymous> (C:\dev\test-project\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:439:9)      
>
> at Compilation.applyPluginsAsyncSeries (C:\dev\test-project\node_modules\tapable\lib\Tapable.js:131:46)      
>
> at Compilation.<anonymous> (C:\dev\test-project\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:621:18)  
>
> at Compilation.applyPluginsAsyncSeries (C:\dev\test-project\node_modules\tapable\lib\Tapable.js:131:46)      
>
> at Compilation.<anonymous> (C:\dev\test-project\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:612:10)  
>
> at next (C:\dev\test-project\node_modules\tapable\lib\Tapable.js:138:11)      
>
> at Compilation.<anonymous> (C:\dev\test-project\node_modules\webpack\lib\optimize\UglifyJsPlugin.js:144:4)
>
> at Compilation.applyPluginsAsyncSeries (C:\dev\test-project\node_modules\tapable\lib\Tapable.js:142:13)      
>
> at Compilation.<anonymous> (C:\dev\test-project\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:607:9)   
>
> at Compilation.applyPluginsAsyncSeries (C:\dev\test-project\node_modules\tapable\lib\Tapable.js:131:46)      
>
> at Compilation.<anonymous> (C:\dev\test-project\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:603:8)   
>
> at Compilation.applyPluginsAsyncSeries (C:\dev\test-project\node_modules\tapable\lib\Tapable.js:131:46)      
>
> at Compilation.seal (C:\dev\test-project\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:551:7)
> ```

I am also unable to `npm start` or `npm run start:prod`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We've updated [MoonMail-UI](https://github.com/microapps/MoonMail-UI) to use latest webpack version along with some code cleanup and improvements. Please pull the last changes, delete `node_modules` folder, if you have one, and run `npm install`